# Converting Brush to SolidColorBrush WinUi 3

Tags: c#, winui-3, brush, solidcolorbrush

Im moving WPF project to WinUi 3.
I would like to convert Brushes.Red/Green to SolidColorBrush. It's used by xaml elements' properties like Background.

```
public SolidColorBrush PowerBrush
{
    get
    {
        if (_powerMode == PowerMode.Off)
        {
            //return (SolidColorBrush)Application.Current.Resources["SystemFillColorCriticalBrush"]; 
            return new SolidColorBrush(Brushes.Red);
        }
        else
        {
            //return (SolidColorBrush)Application.Current.Resources["SystemFillColorSuccessBrush"];
            return Brushes.Green;
        }

    }
}
```

I got errors:

Cannot convert from 'System.Drawing.Brush' to 'Windows.UI.Color'

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Drawing.Brush' to 'Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Media.SolidColorBrush'

How to do it?

Comment: return new SolidColorBrush(((SolidBrush)Brushes.Green).Color);
Cannot convert from 'System.Drawing.Color' to 'Windows.UI.Color'

Comment: Any reason why you dont use the color value constructor?

Comment: I think the downvote is from the bad format of the question.

Comment: At least mark your own answer as 'accepted' for future viewers.

Comment: I need to wait for 3 days to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to convert from Brush used in WPF to SolidColorBrush used in WinUi 3.

The easies way is to use [Microsoft.UI.Colors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.colors?view=winrt-22621) instead of System.Drawing.Brushes for WinUi 3.

```
public SolidColorBrush PowerBrush
{
    get
    {
        if (_powerMode == PowerMode.Off)
        {
            return new(Colors.OrangeRed);
        }
        else
        {
            return new(Colors.Green);
        }
    }
}
```